# Default value of TCP-window size in OS Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, networking

What is the default size of TCP- window in Windows 9x/NT, Windows Me/2000/XP Server 2003 and Linux (Mandriva)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is from 2006, but:

```
Windows: 8192 bytes
FreeBSD: send=32k, receive=56k
Linux: send=16k, receive=43689 bytes (!)
Solaris: 52k
```

Source: *Fundamental Networking in Java,* by yours truly, citing a paper by Bishop et al., *Rigorous Specification and conformance testing techniques for network protocols, as applied to TCP/IP, UDP, and Sockets, University of Cambridge Computer Laboratory & NICTA, Canberra, 2005.*

The Windows value was always much too low and one would hope it has been raised since.

```
OS/2 32-bit: 48k (from memory, but it's been a long time)
```